# GWT VerticalPanel not aligning to top after first widget

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, gwt

I'm trying to create a GWT structure like this:

```
   * RootLayoutPanel
   * --FlowPanel
   * ----VerticalSplitPanel left 
   * ------VerticalPanel top 
   * --------HorizontalPanel top 
   * ----------ListBox top 
   * --------TextArea top 
   * ------VerticalPanel bottom 
   * --------HorizontalPanel bottom 
   * ----------ListBox bottom 
   * --------TextArea bottom
```

Everything works correctly as long as I leave out the TextAreas.  When I add them, they get centered in the VerticalPanel under the HorizontalPanel instead of aligning to the top.  Same thing for checkboxes.

If I look at the HTML being rendered, I see padding under the HorizontalPanel.  I have tried:

```
   leftTopHorizontalPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(0,Unit.PX);
```

and

```
   leftTopTextArea.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(0,Unit.PX);
```

neither of which did anything.  I have tried:

```
   leftTopVerticalPanel.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_TOP);
```

which also did nothing.  I thought all widgets added to a VerticalPanel will continue to align to the top by default?  Suggestions?

EDIT: Here is an image showing what I mean.  Note the checkbox is centered below the dropdown instead of directly under it.  When I adjust the divider, the checkbox stays centered.

[image]

Here is the code that creates the image:

```
private FlowPanel createWatchlistsTab() {
    // FlowPanel will wrap its children as its width resizes with the window
    final FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();

    // *********************** LEFT VERTICAL SPLIT PANEL ***************************
    SplitLayoutPanel leftVerticalSplitPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setSize("30%", "600px");

    // SplitLayoutPanels render as a div. Divs are block elements which always start on a new line.
    // Hence they won't wrap in the FlowPanel unless you make them inline-block, as below.
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INLINE_BLOCK);

    // create the toolbar at the top of the left VerticalSplitPanel
    HorizontalPanel leftTopHorizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    leftTopHorizontalPanel.setWidth("100%");
    leftTopHorizontalPanel.setHeight("25px");
    // leftTopHorizontalPanel.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(0,Unit.PX);

    // create a ListBox, add items, then add it to the HorizontalPanel
    ListBox watchlistDropDown = new ListBox();
    watchlistDropDown.addItem("My Portfolio");
    watchlistDropDown.addItem("Buy Watch");
    leftTopHorizontalPanel.add(watchlistDropDown);

    // create dummy TextArea to be added to the VerticalPanel under the ToolBar
    TextArea leftTopTextArea = new TextArea();
    leftTopTextArea.setWidth("98%");
    leftTopTextArea.setHeight("100%");
    leftTopTextArea.setText("dummy text to show left top widget");
    leftTopTextArea.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(0, Unit.PX);

    // create a VerticalPanel and add the HorizontalPanel and TextArea
    VerticalPanel leftTopVerticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    // leftTopVerticalPanel.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_TOP);
    leftTopVerticalPanel.setWidth("100%");
    leftTopVerticalPanel.setHeight("100%");
    leftTopVerticalPanel.add(leftTopHorizontalPanel);
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("checkbox");
    leftTopVerticalPanel.add(cb);
    // leftTopVerticalPanel.add(leftTopTextArea);

    // add the VerticalPanel to the left top SplitPanel
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.addNorth(leftTopVerticalPanel, 200);
    int minWidth = 200;
    // leftVerticalSplitPanel.setWidgetMinSize(leftTopVerticalPanel, minWidth);
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.setWidgetMinSize(leftTopVerticalPanel, minWidth);

    // add notes TextArea to left bottom VerticalSplitPanel
    TextArea leftBottomTextArea = new TextArea();
    leftBottomTextArea.setWidth("98%");
    leftBottomTextArea.setHeight("100%");
    leftBottomTextArea.setText("dummy text to show left bottom widget");
    leftVerticalSplitPanel.add(leftBottomTextArea);

    // add the left VerticalSplitPanel to the FlowPanel
    flowPanel.add(leftVerticalSplitPanel);
```

Comment: By creating a similar structure I could not replicate the behavior that you have mentioned. Please add your code to the question and maybe a screenshot with an explanation of the changes you want to achieve.

Comment: I added an image.  I'll work on getting the associated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`VerticalPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html) (`leftTopVerticalPanel`) is rendered as a `<table>`.

You set its height to 100%:

```
leftTopVerticalPanel.setHeight("100%");
```

which makes it to fill all the available space in the north of the [`SplitLayoutPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html) (`leftVerticalSplitPanel`).

So the `<table>` is stretched vertically and thus its rows are also stretched evenly.

See below DOM structure:

[image: DOM]

---

Comment out the line with `setHeight("100%")` and you will have your checkbox directly under dropdown:

[image: outcome]

Comment: Thank you Adam.  I set the VerticalPanel's height to expand or contract when the divider is moved.  Therefore, I thought it should be set to 100%.  I don't understand why it shouldn't.  But you're right, it works.